# Expandable ListView with checkbox gets random checkbox checked without user checking it

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I'm doing a college project alone and I have stumble on a problem...
Every time I check a checkbox in my list view, when I scroll down or up, other checkboxes gets checked, I don't know how to fix this. Could someone help me??

See the code below, it works, I just don't know how to maintain checked only the checkbox the user wants, without checking and unchecking random others...

**MAIN**

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import static android.os.SystemClock.sleep;
import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;

public class Etapas extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, GroupInfo> subjects = new LinkedHashMap<String, GroupInfo>();
    private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList = new ArrayList<GroupInfo>();

    private CustomAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView simpleExpandableListView;
    private static Button buttonSalvar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_etapas);
        setTitle("Etapas");
        onButtonClickListener();

        // add data for displaying in expandable list view
        loadData();

        //get reference of the ExpandableListView
        simpleExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleExpandableListView);
        // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Etapas.this, deptList);
        // attach the adapter to the expandable list view
        simpleExpandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //expand all the Groups
        //expandAll();

        // setOnChildClickListener listener for child row click
        simpleExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                //get the group header
                GroupInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);
                //get the child info
                ChildInfo detailInfo = headerInfo.getProductList().get(childPosition);
                //display it or do something with it
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Clicked on :: " + headerInfo.getName()
//                        + "/" + detailInfo.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        // setOnGroupClickListener listener for group heading click
        simpleExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                //get the group header
                GroupInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);
                //display it or do something with it
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Etapa: " + headerInfo.getName(),
//                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    public void onButtonClickListener(){
        buttonSalvar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        buttonSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Etapas.this);
                a_builder.setMessage("Deseja salvar?")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                                    //Aqui tem que pegar as checkbox e dar update no banco
                                    makeText(Etapas.this,"Salvo com sucesso!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   // makeText(Etapas.this,"Salvo com sucesso!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    //sleep(500);
                                    finish();
                                }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        }
        );
    }

    //method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            simpleExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    //method to collapse all groups
    private void collapseAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            simpleExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }

    //load some initial data into out list
    private void loadData() {

        addProduct("Etapa 1", "Marcação da obra",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 1", "Valetas e brocas",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 1", "Alicerce e impermeabilização",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 1", "30 % alvenaria (altura de 1,20m)",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 1", "Contra-verga com canaleta e concreto armado com treliça",false);

        addProduct("Etapa 2", "Final da alvenaria",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 2", "Verga nas portas e janelas com canaleta e concreto armado com treliça",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 2", "Vigas de respaldo",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 2", "Colocação da laje",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 2", "Concretagem da laje",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 2", "Entrada de água e energia e colocação das caixinhas na laje",false);

        addProduct("Etapa 3", "Telhado (pulverizar madeira com cupicida)",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 3", "Elétrica ( eletrodutos e caixinhas nas paredes)",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 3", "Encanamento de água",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 3", "50% encanamento de esgoto e águas pluviais( Colocar Caixa de gordura)",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 3", "70 % chapisco e reboco interno",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 3", "Contra-piso interno",false);

        addProduct("Etapa 4", "Colocar os batentes e as janelas Sassazaki",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "Terminar reboco interno",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "70% reboco e chapisco externo",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "100% azulejo",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "50% piso",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "Início da pintura (Selador nos cômodos liberados)",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "Cimentado externo",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 4", "Final de hidráulica, esgoto",false);

        addProduct("Etapa 5", "Terminar reboco externo",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 5", "Terminar colocação do piso e rodapé; soleiras e peitoris",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 5", "Assentar portas e fechaduras",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 5", "Final da pintura",false);

        addProduct("Etapa 6", "Colocação do vaso sanitário, lavatório, pia e tanque",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 6", "Final da elétrica (enfiação, espelhos das caixinhas)",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 6", "Limpeza geral da casa",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 6", "Retirada do Habite-se",false);
        addProduct("Etapa 6", "Averbação em cartório.",false);

    }


    //here we maintain our products in various departments
    private int addProduct(String department, String product, boolean status) {

        int groupPosition = 0;
        status = false;

        //check the hash map if the group already exists
        GroupInfo headerInfo = subjects.get(department);
        //add the group if doesn't exists
        if (headerInfo == null) {
            headerInfo = new GroupInfo();
            headerInfo.setName(department);
            subjects.put(department, headerInfo);
            deptList.add(headerInfo);
        }

        //get the children for the group
        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = headerInfo.getProductList();
        //size of the children list
        int listSize = productList.size();
        //add to the counter
        listSize++;

        //create a new child and add that to the group
        ChildInfo detailInfo = new ChildInfo();
        detailInfo.setSequence(String.valueOf(listSize));
        detailInfo.setName(product);
        detailInfo.setStatus(false);
        productList.add(detailInfo);
        headerInfo.setProductList(productList);

        //find the group position inside the list
        groupPosition = deptList.indexOf(headerInfo);
        return groupPosition;
    }
}
```

**ADAPTER**

```
/**
 * Created by RicardoFernandes on 04/03/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.deptList = deptList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
        return productList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
        }

        TextView sequence = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sequence);
        sequence.setText(detailInfo.getSequence().trim() + ". ");
        CheckBox childItem = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
        childItem.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());
        if(childItem.isChecked()){
            childItem.setChecked(true);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
        return productList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return deptList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return deptList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        GroupInfo headerInfo = (GroupInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
        }

        TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**GROUP INFO**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by RicardoFernandes on 04/03/2017.
 */

public class GroupInfo {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<ChildInfo> list = new ArrayList<ChildInfo>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<ChildInfo> getProductList() {
        return list;
    }



    public void setProductList(ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList) {
        this.list = productList;
    }
}
```

**CHILD INFO**

```
/**
 * Created by RicardoFernandes on 04/03/2017.
 */

   public class ChildInfo {

    private String sequence = "";
    private String name = "";
    private boolean status = false;

    public String getSequence() {
        return sequence;
    }

    public void setSequence(String sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean getProductStatus(){
        return true;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {this.status = status;}

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    }
```

**activity_etapas.xml** - (MAIN XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_etapas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="@color/colorMarrom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#706e6e"
        android:childDivider="#a9afa9"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Salvar"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/logo_v_1_5"
            android:elevation="17dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorMarrom"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**child_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sequence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="35sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/childItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sequence"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:checked="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**group_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    tools:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="35sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A *view* is a visual representation of your *data*. When you (un)check a checkbox you need to reflect that in your data set. When you initialize a checkbox before showing, you read state from that data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getChildView() you are reusing the views:

```
if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
}
```

So any changes you make to the Checkbox will be visible when it is reused (i.e. when you scroll or refresh the list).

To solve this you need to handle both cases of the conditional statement - i.e. follow the if with an else to ensure your view is reset to a default state.

```
if (detailInfo.isChecked()){
    childItem.setChecked(true);
} else {
    childItem.setChecked(false);
}

// Equal to

childItem.setChecked(detailInfo.isChecked());
```

You will need to add a getter and setter to your ChildInfo class and update this using a check box listener:

```
childItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        detailInfo.setChecked(isChecked);
   }
});
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

Bro Do one thing:-

In your **CHILD INFO** class create a getter setter method

setisChecked(boolean ischecked);
getisChecked();

And, when you check any check box call list.get(position).setisChecked(true);
And , in your getChildView Method do this:-

```
if(list.get(position).getisChecked()){
checkbox.setChecked(true);
}else{
checkbox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Thats, it Enjoy coding ....